# Simple rounding with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, rounding

I have a scenario where I need to round to the next 5kgs.

if the total weight is less than 5kgs, I need to round it to the next 5kgs. 
if the item is just over 5kgs, for instance, 5.01 it needs to round up to 10kgs.

My math skills aren't the greatest, so Im hoping someone might be able to show me how to calculate it so it jumps to the next 5 kgs automatically

```
<cfset totalWeight = 5.01>
<cfset breakPoints = 5.00>
<cfset bagCost     = 18.00>
<cfset totalWeight = ceiling(totalWeight)>

<cfif totalWeight LTE 5.00 >
    <cfset totalBags = 1 >
<cfelse>
    <cfset totalBags = totalWeight / breakpoints >
</cfif>
<cfset totalCost = totalBags * bagCost>

<cfoutput>
#totalweight#<br/>
#totalBags#
<hr/>
#totalCost#<br/>
<hr/>

</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something like this, the math logic is to divide the original value by 5, round it, and then multiply by 5.   This guarantees you the next multiple of 5.

```
<CFSET RoundedValue = ceiling(totalWeight / 5) * 5>
```

Since you always want to round up, we use the CEILING function.   If merely rounding to the nearest 5 (up or down), we would use the ROUND function instead.